# Rails: link_to with block and GET params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, actionview

How can I achieve query string and URL parameters in a `link_to` block declaration? Right now, I have this, which works:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', :edit, :type => 'book', :id => book %>
```

The above works, and outputs:

```
http://localhost:3000/books/edit/1?type=book
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
<% link_to :edit, :type => 'book', :id => book do %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

But the above format outputs:

```
http://localhost:3000/books/edit/
```

Which isn't what I'm looking for... I want it to output a URL like the previous example.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13):

[`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001597) takes the same options that [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000649) does. <del>Having said that, there is no `:type` option and it doesn't really accept blocks, so my guess is that the reason the your second example works is because it's located within the scope of a Book view.</del> As mentioned by [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711294/rails-link-to-with-block-and-get-params/2711571#comment-2736417) in a reply to this answer, passing a block to `link_to` can be used as a replacement for the first argument (the link text).

If Book is a resource, you can get the `link_to` helper to generate the URL you're looking for by passing it one of the handy, automatically generated resource routes rails makes for you. Run `rake routes` before you try this:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_book_path(book) %>
```

Otherwise, you can explicitly state what controller/action you want to link to:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", :controller => "books", :action => "edit", :id => book %>
```

Happy hacking.

**EDIT:** Almost forgot, you CAN add query strings bypassing them in AFTER you declare the id of the object you're linking to.

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_book_path(book, :query1 => "value", :query2 => "value")
```

Would product `/books/1/edit?query1=value&query2=value`. Alternatively:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", :controller => "books", :action => "edit", :id => book, :query1 => "value", :query2 => "value" %>
```

Comment: The block seems to be a way of capturing input to place within the `<a>tags</a>`. http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M002452

Answer (score 0):

Try Follwing

```
<% link_to(:edit, :type => 'book', :id => book) do %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

or to achieve same url Use

```
<% link_to(:action=>'edit', :type => 'book', :id => book) do %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't know if you're sending the `do ... end` block to `link_to` or `book`, and is sending it to `book` because it is closer to the block. `book do ... end` returns `nil`, so you're left with `link_to :edit, :type=>'book', :id=>nil`.  You will need to bracket the parameters, and while you're at it, I would rewrite it to be more understandable with a controller, action, id setup: `link_to{:controller=>"books",:action=>"edit",:id=>book}do ... end`

Answer (score 0):

in mime_types.rb file add:

Mime::Type.register "text/application", :book